# Vuetify bottom navigation inaccessible after scrolling then changing route

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js, vue-router

I am having trouble with `v-bottom-navigation` `hide-on-scroll` on route change. If I am on a route with scrollable content and I scroll down then up, it works as expected - the bottom nav is hidden. Then, on route change to a page with no scrollable content, the bottom nav is inaccessible. There is no obvious way to reset its `tranform` style that `hide-on-scroll` set, other than go to a page with scrollable content, then scroll down.

Repro:
[codePen](https://codepen.io/chrizzis/pen/wvdZgEE)

1. scroll to bottom of page 1, then scroll up (bottom nav is transitioned)
2. nav to page 2 (hamburger button)
3. Nav is transitioned off-screen

```
<v-main>
  <v-container fluid>
    <v-fade-transition mode="out-in">
      <router-view></router-view>
    </v-fade-transition>
  </v-container>
</v-main>
<v-bottom-navigation
  hide-on-scroll
  grow
  app
>...</v-bottom-navigation>
```

Thanks.

Comment: How about use `v-model` on `v-bottom-navigation` and set it to true whenever route change?

Comment: [It didn't work](https://codepen.io/chrizzis/pen/JjNVvxv). I need to override the style: `transform: translateY(100%);` that `hide-on-scroll` applies. But how to do it on route change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Kael in the Vuetify discord #help channel for the [solution](https://codepen.io/chrizzis/pen/xxdezgy): use `:input-value.sync` to open it on route change.

```
    <v-bottom-navigation
      :input-value.sync="bottomNav"
      hide-on-scroll
      grow
      app
    >
```

```
  watch: {
    '$route.path' () {
      this.bottomNav = true
    }
```